# Unable to save variable to table storage from Azure QnA chat bot C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, chatbot

I am trying to save a single variable "userinput" into my Azure table storage, the variable populates with the first message the user send to the chat bot, when the user sends "no" to the bot.

This is my current code for uploading the variable "userinput" into my table storage:

```
private void storeuserinput(Activity activity)
{
    var uid = activity.From.Id;
    var uname = activity.From.Name;

    if (activity.Text?.ToLower().ToString() == "no" || activity.Text?.ToLower().ToString() == "NO" || activity.Text?.ToLower().ToString() == "No" || activity.Text?.ToLower().ToString() == "Nope" || activity.Text?.ToLower().ToString() == "nope")
    {
        var userinput = firstmessage;

        // Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to the table.
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("NoSolutionFound");

        // Create a new customer entity.
        unansweredQuestion input = new unansweredQuestion();
        input.Query = userinput;

        // Create the TableOperation object that inserts the customer entity.
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(input);

        // Execute the insert operation.
        table.Execute(insertOperation);
    }

    //extract other data from "activity" object

    //your code logic here
    //store data in your table storage

    //Note: specifcial scenario of user send attachment
}

public class unansweredQuestion : TableEntity
{
    public unansweredQuestion() { } // the parameter-less constructor must be provided

    public string Query { get; set; }
}
```

My storage table remains empty when my code is run and two errors appear inthe output box:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Error: 102 : Role environment .
> FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024894
>
> Getting "StorageConnectionString" from ServiceRuntime: FAIL.
>
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

Comment: Have you checked here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190878/getting-storageconnectionstring-from-serviceruntime-fail#25157641

Comment: @Pierre-MarieLeBrun Yes unfortunately this does not resolve my issue

Comment: Would this be because the chat bot template from azure doe not have a main?