# How CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("") actually works?

Tags: .net, azure, app-config, azure-service-runtime

I am using CloudConfigurationManager for getting my connection string.
I have created one ***Azure Service Fabric Application**.

```
storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
```

It is working fine, but i can see this as well:
[image]

**Getting "StorageConnectionString" from ServiceRuntime: FAIL.**

Kindly explain why is it showing such **FAIL** message. Also how is this CloudConfigurationManager works?

**Note**:Do not tag any workarounds, as I have seen them all.
Here are the links that I already visited, but not satisfied.

[Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190878/getting-storageconnectionstring-from-serviceruntime-fail) and 
    [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837191/how-do-i-make-cloudconfigurationmanager-getsetting-less-verbose?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Is `StorageConnectionString` defined in service configuration file (*.cscfg)?

Comment: No it is in my app.config file. Actually I am new to azure and trying to understand it.

Comment: Try to define this setting in service configuration file. Role environment picks it up from there if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Kindly explain why is it showing such FAIL message. Also how is this CloudConfigurationManager works?

AFAIK, [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager/) is just a stand-alone library with no dependencies. And it describes as follows:

> Microsoft Azure Configuration Manager provides a unified API to load configuration settings regardless of where the application is hosted - whether on-premises or in a Cloud Service.

The `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` would read the configuration settings from the appropriate configuration store. If your application is running as a .NET Web application, the `GetSetting` method would retrieve the setting value from the `Web.config` or `app.config` file. While the application is running in Windows Azure Cloud Service or in a Windows Azure Website, the `GetSetting` would retrieve the setting value from the `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg`.

Use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), we could find the `GetSetting` method would check the **ServiceRuntime** provider firstly and leverage [RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(string configurationSettingName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.getconfigurationsettingvalue.aspx) for getting the setting value. If the value is `null`, then it would use the **ConfigurationManager** provider and leverage `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings['<settingName>'];`.

```html
internal string GetSetting(string name, bool outputResultsToTrace)
{
    string value = AzureApplicationSettings.GetValue("ServiceRuntime", name, new Func<string, string>(this.GetServiceRuntimeSetting), outputResultsToTrace);
    if (value == null)
    {
        string arg_44_0 = "ConfigurationManager";
        Func<string, string> arg_44_2;
        if ((arg_44_2 = AzureApplicationSettings.<>c.<>9__10_0) == null)
        {
            arg_44_2 = (AzureApplicationSettings.<>c.<>9__10_0 = new Func<string, string>(AzureApplicationSettings.<>c.<>9.<GetSetting>b__10_0));
        }
        value = AzureApplicationSettings.GetValue(arg_44_0, name, arg_44_2, outputResultsToTrace);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Since you configured the settings in your `app.config` file, and the `GetSetting` method would write log to Trace by default, then you would see the trace logs as you provided. Additionally, you could use `GetSetting('<settingName>',false)` for disable the trace log.